# starting activity needs application call, android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

today i wanted to add a functionnality in my app, after downloading the code and adding it to my project files, it seems that before calling the main activity of this functionnality, a class(AppController) extending Application should be called first! Because its onCreate methode initialise some important things:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
mInstance = this;
pref = new PrefManager(this);
}
```

so the think is: before doing that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Wallapers.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

i should call the application AppController.
In the code project i have downloaded it's called in the android manifest, but since i already have an application called there i can't call more than one.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to merge the code for both the Application classes into one, and assign that name in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Let's say you have two Application java files `MyApplication.java` and `AppController.java`.

You have said that `AppController.java` has

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    pref = new PrefManager(this);
}
```

Then merge into `onCreate()` of `MyApplication.java` as follows

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Code from MyApplication.java

    mInstance = this;
    pref = new PrefManager(this);
}
```

I am guessing you are new to this. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: it's exactly what i did and it works perfectly, thank you Awanish !